# R: Integral of the pdf of uniform (-0.0001,0.0001) over more than whole interval is showing zero

Tags: r

Consider pdf of uniform distribution over (-0.0001,0.0001) as

```
 f1=function(x){dunif(x,-0.0001,0.0001)}
```

Now integrate it over (-1,1)

```
 integrate(f1,-1,1)
```

Output is 0 instead of 1:

```
0 with absolute error < 0
```

Surprised to see the outcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce here: I get `1 with absolute error < 1.1e-14`. (R version 3.3.0.)

Comment: Thanks. corrected my question.

Comment: Okay, that's a lot less surprising (and I can reproduce). Remember that all R can do is sample the function at particular points; it's not really surprising if its integration algorithm happens to miss the tiny portion of the interval where `f1` is nonzero.

Comment: From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/integrate.html): "Like all numerical integration routines, these evaluate the function on a finite set of points. If the function is approximately constant (in particular, zero) over nearly all its range it is possible that the result and error estimate may be seriously wrong."

Comment: Try `plot(f1, -1,1)`. The function is almost everywhere equal to zero, except for a very narrow range around x=0. A numerical integration of such a function often leads to a result that is almost exactly zero.

Comment: Thanks..got the point.